# Ошибка при подключении paypal к yii2 starter kit

Tags: yii2, paypal

Пытаюсь подключить paypal sdk к yii2 starter kit используюя marciocamello/yii2-paypal. Выполняю данные [инструкции](https://packagist.org/packages/andrey-klimenko/yii2-paypal)

Добавляю код в проект:

```html
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist marciocamello/yii2-paypal "*"
```

Добавились:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также добаляю данные строки в конфиг:

```html
'paypal'=> [
    'class'        => 'marciocamello\Paypal',
    'clientId'     => '...мои значения...',
    'clientSecret' => '...мои значения...',
    'isProduction' => false,
     // This is config file for the PayPal system
     'config'       => [
         'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
         'http.Retry'             => 1,
    ]
],
```

Выполнив

```html
Yii::$app->paypal;
```

получаю

Class marciocamello\Paypal does not exist

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Смотрели в autoload.php? Класс точно зарегистрировался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько могу судить по [исходникам на гитхабе](https://github.com/marciocamello/yii2-paypal/blob/master/Paypal.php), класс лежит по адресу `marciocamello\yii2-paypal\Paypal`, а не `marciocamello\Paypal`.

Comment: изменил на marciocamello\yii2-paypal\Paypal, ошибка Class marciocamello\yii2-paypal\Paypal does not exist

Comment: @user2667757 попробуйте добавить обратный слеш в начало